# how good is monotouch and mono for android comparing with native code?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin

I make small investigation how good is monotouch and mono for android comparing with native code? What I need is numbers and maybe some other info about advantages and disadvantages of monotouch and mono for android...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have comparison figures but I have used both MonoTouch and MonoDroid for an OpenGL application.

The type of application your making may make the difference to you.
If you want to create a cross platform application I personally would go with Mono as its probably going to be more productive in the end.

I have must say MonoTouch outperforms MonoDroid, probably because of the .NET to java interop that must take place on Android (and the Java on Android seams to be slow)[At least android 2.2+ devices].

There is also Mono.Simd if you need speed optimizations.

**UPDATE: "Mono.Simd" is not available on MonoTouch or MonoDroid.**

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a real answer, but in my opinion, it is the best. You can get both a native app as well as lots of code re-use. There are lots of things out there that could help you make a decision, but also look at the Xamarin blog.

Answer (score 0):

here a link that may help you :

http://www.koushikdutta.com/2009/01/dalvik-vs-mono.html

based on that mono is way faster than java dalvik!